# Mailhog Setup in Laravel 6.x

Tags: laravel, homestead, laravel-6

Using Laravel 6.0, I have configured my `.env` file to utilize Mailhog in my local environment as explained in the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead#configuring-mailhog).

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=0.0.0.0
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I can go to `http://localhost:8025` and see the Mailhog interface.

However, when I try to send an email either through a controller method or on my local file system via `php artisan tinker`, no mail gets through.

**The only time mail does get through** to Mailhog is if I `vagrant ssh` and run `php artisan tinker` from inside of there.

This is all I'm trying to send: `Mail::raw('FROM HOME CONTROLLER', function ($message){ $message->to('contact@contact.com');});`

I have tried using MAIL_HOST=localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.10.10. I've tried different user/pass combos (testuser, password, testpass, etc), to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was not going through was a simple route misconfiguration (accessing the wrong route in my web.php router file).

Still unable to get it working via `php artisan tinker` locally though, which I would imagine has to do with PHP mail not actually being present without being inside of the vagrant instance.